# Selenium Webdrive (Java) - find an element in xpath where is no specific attribute

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following statement:

```
String v_name = "Computer";

String v_test1 = new WebDriverWait(Login.driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.xpath("//span[.=\""+v_name+"\"]/following-sibling::span"))).getText();
```

I need to get somehow the value with no style="display: none;".

```
<div class="test">
    <span>WIN-S38B7T042RC</span>
    <span style="display: none;>CLOSED</span>
    <span>OPENED</span>
    <span style="display: none;>CLOSED</span>
</div>
```

I can't use options like span[1].

So, I want to find some more flexible option.

Something like : `/following-sibling::span **not in** style="display: none;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use this xpath, easiest and simpliest

```
//span[not(contains(@style, 'display: none;'))]
```

Comment: I agree, I am using it : //span[.=""+v_name+""]/following-sibling::span[not(contains(@style, 'display: none;'))]

Answer (score 0):

XPath is quite flexible; one way would be something like this:

```
By.xpath("//span[not(contains(@style, 'display: none;'))]/")
```

or probably even something like this:

```
By.xpath("//span[not(@style)]/")
```

Of course you can also use something similar to what you tried, e.g.

```
By.xpath("//span[/following-sibling::span/@style]/")
```

But that's probably more complicated than necessary.

Mind you, none of these are tested but they should work in theory.

Comment: Thanks, I checked one of them it's find for me ://span[.=""+v_name+""]/following-sibling::span[not(contains(@style, 'display: none;'))]

Comment: function xpath text() could not work with selenium. Exception will throw

Comment: Is there some way to make the same NOT using CSSSELECTOR? I think cssselector in this case will work faster

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang Thanks, I wasn't aware that Selenium doesn't support `text()` (though I believe that probably depends on the XPath engine that's used, as Selenium can use several). I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: for cssselector, you could use span:not([style])